# On highlight an external file page load seems to fail

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, highlight.js

Trying to highlight an external file `main.cpp` with highlight.js I put together the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/default.min.css">

    <title>My Node.js Server</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello from Node.js!</h1>

    <pre><code class="cpp" id="codeContainer">int x = 5;</code></pre>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<!-- and it's easy to individually load additional languages -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/languages/cpp.min.js"></script> -->

<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

<script>
    document.write("casdca");
</script>

    <script>
        fetch('main.cpp')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                const codeContainer = document.getElementById('codeContainer');
                codeContainer.textContent = text; 
                hljs.highlightElement(codeContainer);
            });
        hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

However it seems page loading is failing, since I see the actual `index.html` source code in the browser.

Comment on `codeContainer.textContent = text;` and following lines depending on it cause the page to load, but not presenting `main.cpp` obviously.

All this is being loaded by

```
node node.js
```

which is

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end("Error loading the page");
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end(data);
        }
    });
});

const PORT = 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

Wondering what I'm missing. Appreciate if one can give me some directions.

Answer (score 0):

node.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end('Error loading index.html');
            } else {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                res.end(data);
            }
        });
    } else if (req.url === '/load-text') {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'main.cpp'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end('Error loading file');
            } else {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                res.end(data);
            }
        });
    }
});

const PORT = 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

Using [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

    <title>My Node.js Server</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello from Node.js!</h1>

    <pre><code id="codeContainer">casdcas</code></pre>

    <script>
        fetch('/load-text')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                const codeContainer = document.getElementById('codeContainer');
                codeContainer.textContent = text;
                hljs.highlightElement(codeContainer); 
            }).catch(err => console.error('Error fetching the text file:', err));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Using [prism.js](https://prismjs.com)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/toolbar/prism-toolbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/match-braces/prism-match-braces.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <title>My Node.js Server</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello from Node.js!</h1>

    <pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
    
    <pre class="line-numbers"><code class="language-cpp match-braces" id="codeContainer">int x = 5;</code></pre>

    <script>
        fetch('/load-text')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                const codeContainer = document.getElementById('codeContainer');
                codeContainer.textContent = text;
            }).catch(err => console.error('Error fetching the text file:', err));
    </script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/components/prism-core.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/autoloader/prism-autoloader.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/toolbar/prism-toolbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/copy-to-clipboard/prism-copy-to-clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/match-braces/prism-match-braces.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

prism is better because it shows line numbers, the copy button, match-braces, and other plugins.